# Python pyinstaller error when converting py to exe

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am trying to convert my py to exe by pyinstaller, however it responses error message.

Thank you!

What I entered below,

```
PS E:\Python\Scripts> pyinstaller.exe --onefile d:\Python Projects\Concept Number Generator\Concept Number Generator.py
```

What response was:

```
71 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.6
71 INFO: Python: 3.8.1
72 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.17763-SP0
73 INFO: wrote E:\Python\Scripts\Python.spec
77 INFO: UPX is not available.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\python\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "e:\python\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "E:\Python\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "e:\python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 114, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "e:\python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 65, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "e:\python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 734, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "e:\python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 681, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "E:\Python\Scripts\Python.spec", line 6, in <module>
    a = Analysis(['d:\\Python', 'Projects\\Concept', 'Number', 'Generator\\Concept', 'Number', 'Generator.py'],
  File "e:\python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 191, in __init__
    raise ValueError("script '%s' not found" % script)
ValueError: script 'd:\Python' not found
```

Comment: You need to out paths with spaces in quotes. Right now the path is being interpreted as a number of separate arguments.

Comment: `pyinstaller.exe --onefile "d:\Python Projects\Concept Number Generator"\"Concept Number Generator.py"`

Comment: Thank you! I watched a Youtube guy showing me without a quote, so i deleted manually. So silly..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, when you enter it without a quotation mark it interprets them as individual arguments and hence this leads to the given error.

Simply encapsulate them within the quotation mark

```
pyinstaller.exe --onefile "d:\Python Projects\Concept Number Generator"\"Concept Number Generator.py"
```

This should solve the problem.